# is it possible to create an automated report that gives "all time" numbers for page views

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to create an automated weekly report in Google Analytics and send that to certain people that want to see their all time numbers. I only see the option to set up last 30 days, when setting up the report.

Is there any other way to get this? If not, what about creating a custom range that starts a certain date, but the end date should always be current date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using the Google Analytics [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/). Just set the `start-date` to sometime prior to setting up your account (e.g. `2005-01-01`) and set the `end-date` value to `today`.

If you want to automate reports, I suggest you check out the [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics/fefimfimnhjjkomigakinmjileehfopp). It uses the Core Reporting API under the hood and was built to make tasks like this really easy.

Here's an introduction to the add-on and some videos explaining how to use it.
http://analytics.blogspot.com/2015/01/simplify-your-google-analytics.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick reply, will explore more on the spreadsheet add-on.

what would you put for Last N Days, given that i would always want the numbers to date?

Comment: Don't use "Last N Days", just use the date range as I described above.